# Learn Python the Hard Way Example 5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

In the Example 5 of `Learn Python the Hard Way` I ran into a problem. I went ahead and converted the inches to centimeters and the pounds to kilograms. I ran into an error though with the formatter and the syntax error read `not all arguments converted during string formatting`. My inches to cm and pounds to kg is fine but it didn't show the variable in the string. It looked like this:

```
print "%s is", cm, "tall in centimeters." % name
```

I was having a hard time posting the variables because it wants to be posted a certain way. The variables aren't the issue I'm confused why my variable didn't print using the formatter. I even tried it with `%r` instead of `%s` but it still wouldn't print the name variable. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4):

use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
print "{0} is {1} tall in centimeters.".format(name, cm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string formatting is acting on this :

```
"tall in centimeters." % name
```

As `%s` is not found in the above string, the interpreter fails.

A way to do what you want :

```
print "%s is %s tall in centimeters." % (name, cm)
```

Or

```
print "%s is %.2f tall in centimeters." % (name, cm)
```

if you'd like to show `cm` on 2 digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can do in two common ways -

Using the old way (`%`):

```
print "%s is %s tall in centimeters." % (name, cm)
```

References: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Using the new way (`format`)

```
print "{} is {} tall in centimeters.".format(name, cm)
```

References: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting

Please note using `format` is a good practice since it's the new way. You can read more about these on this website: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep your syntax:

```
print "%s is" %name, cm, "tall in centimeters."
```

the string referenced in the first print section needs to follow immediately.